# Still having trouble understanding .ToString()

Tags: c#

The question is "Override the ToString() method to return all data members.

when I return _name is gives me errors that it does not exist in current context. I do not understand how this should look in order to return all the data members

```
sing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication297
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String name = "Stormtrooper";
            Employee s = new Employee(name);
            Console.WriteLine("The type of hire is a {0}", s.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("The identification number is {0}", s.Number);
            Console.WriteLine("The date of hire is {0} ABY", s.Date);
            Console.WriteLine("The standard galactic salary is...{0:C}", s.Salary);
        }

        class Employee
        {
            private string _name;
            private string _number;
            private int _date;
            private int _salary;

            public string Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return _name;
                }
            }
    
            public string Number
            {
                get
                {
                    return _number;
                }
            }
    
            public int Date
            {
                get
                {
                    return _date;
                }
            }
    
            public int Salary
            {
                get
                {
                    return _salary;
                }
            }

            public Employee(string n)
            {
                _name = n;
                _number = "AA23TK421";
                _date = 4;
                _salary = 800;
            }
        }
    
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return HOW DO I RETURN THIS???
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sloppy indenting problem.  Type Ctrl+E, Ctrl+D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The override of `ToString` needs to be inside the `Employee` type, not outside of it.

```
public class Employee {
  ...
  public override string ToString() { 
    return String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", _name, _number, _date, _salary);
  }
}
```

Once this is done any calls to `Employee::ToString` will return that formatted string instead of the default one

Comment: oh my sweet god.... 6-7 weeks into programming and I still make dumb errors like this =(

Comment: @Azzamean 10+ years of programming and I still make dumb errors every day.  Welcome to life as a programmer. It can be humiliating at times.  Learn to take it with a smile :)

Comment: What exactly does this .ToString() method do? It seems like I put a line of code in here that didn't change anything or do much? Although I am sure I am completely wrong about this. I am reading in my book and it explains it in 2 pages and gives nothing really useful..

Comment: Don't feel so bad!  _Everyone_ makes mistakes.  Experience will help you understand, find, and fix them faster.  But we all still make them.

Comment: @Azzamean the method itself is attempting to summarize your object in a single line of text.  This will be visible anytime you call `ToString` on an instance of `Employee` (even if it's converted to an instance of `Object`).  A way to make this visible is change your original Main method to have the following line `Console.WriteLine(s)`.  Then run that program twice: one with my method added, and once with it commented out

Comment: JaredPar thank you. I wonder why Barbara Doyle, the author of this C# book, couldn't have summarized it so simply. Makes sense now that I am looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

Your ToString() method is not inside your Employee class.  It needs to be moved up before the second closing brace after the Employee constructor.  In other words:

```
    public Employee(string n)
    {
        _name = n;
        _number = "AA23TK421";
        _date = 4;
        _salary = 800;
    }
//} remove this end brace

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _name; // or whatever you want the result to be
    }
}  // brace moved to here
```

Answer (score 1):

The ToString() method can return a single string.

If you wise to return all the data members in a single string, you need to format it.

Something like:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return(string.format("Name={0}, Number={1}...", _name, _number));
}
```